#  Routing a url to fetch content from another site

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Environment: IIS 7.

- I have a default site `www.domain.com`. Folder C:Inetpub/wwwroot/domain
- There is subdomain `www.subdomain.domain.com`. Folder C:Inetpub/wwwroot/domain/subdomain.
- Now, I have set up a new website at an external server, say `www.newdomain.com`. I cannot host `www.newdomain.com` on the same IIS server (as mentioned above) due to some constraints.

In this setup, how do I get `www.subdomain.domain.com/blog` to show all the content available on `www.newdomain.com` while preserving the URL as `www.subdomain.domain.com/blog`

How could this be achieved in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put the entire `www.subdomain.domain.com` on the other server. You can't put just the `/blog` path somewhere else.

How would any client know to go to that other server for `/blog` if the DNS for the subdomain points to the first server?

Alternatively, you could create `blog.subdomain.domain.com` for the blog server.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approaches:

- Host the new website as `blog.domain.com` with the actual content hosted on a different server (not the same IIS server as `domain.com`)
- Set-up a ProxyPass on `subdomain.domain.com/blog` to the new website. I know how do to this on Apache (via mod_proxy and ProxyPass), but not sure how to do this with IIS. Probably [ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do this by reverse proxy rewrite rule. For those who have similar trouble here is the solution:

Go to the site node hosting www.subdomain.domain.com and click rewrite rule. If ARR is not installed the IIS Manager will ask you to install it. After installing ARR close and reopen the IIS Manager.

Open the rewrite rule window. There will be a dialog asking to allow reverse proxy to servers outside your server farm, accept that. In the Inbound rule enter www.newdomain.com. In the from input of the Outbound rule enter www.newdomain.com and in the to input enter www.subdomain.domain.com. click apply changes.

This will route the entire www.subdomain.domain.com to newdomain.com. What you need is to route only the /blog link.

To do this go to rewrite rules and select the rewrite rule you just created. Click edit and in the match section in url input change (.asterix) to ^blog(.asterix). This will apply the rule to route only the /blog.

That all. test your routing in the browser, if everythings fine this should work.